# Angular 2+ app IIS hosted route does not work on reload

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting, routes

I am having angular 2+ app  hosted on IIS 8. All routes are client side  routes except for some route  starting with /mutual-funds/*.For those route ,I want to make IIS get that folder and use its index page.I have written rewrite rules but it does not work on reload.Any   help would be appreciated.

The web config file is:

```
 <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/webapp/" />
    </rule>





     <rule name="Check1" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="/mutual-funds/"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{ REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/webapp/mutual-funds/" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested if someone have a response.

As a workaround, you can use the Hash Location Strategy adding `{ useHash: true }` where you provide the router :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```

It will add a '#' after in the URL. Then you can access your page with the URL `http://your-context/#mutual-funds`

Here a goot article about location strategy : https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/

Comment: i don't want to use HashLocationStratgey.